# Why i can find the Javascript Array forEach method in Array properties object ?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm dealing with ECMAScript 6 with the function Reflect.ownKeys(Array)). The properties i get are :

```
  console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(Array))
  ["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "isArray", "from", "of", Symbol(Symbol.species)]
```

but i still can use the **forEach** method on the array ! But i can't find where the function forEach is defined such as property !

Answer (score 5):

`Array` is the constructor. Look at the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) instead:

```
console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(Array.prototype));
```

Result:

```
["length", "constructor", "toString", "toLocaleString", "join", "pop", "push", "reverse", "shift", "unshift", "slice", "splice", "sort", "filter", "forEach", "some", "every", "map", "indexOf", "lastIndexOf", "reduce", "reduceRight", "copyWithin", "find", "findIndex", "fill", "includes", "entries", "keys", "concat", Symbol(Symbol.unscopables), Symbol(Symbol.iterator)]
```

Comment: Thanks !! I did't get it !!

Comment: All the Array methods like forEach() or reverse() or reduce() or whatever you look for are functions of Array.prototype so that all arrays can share them.